# How we load other languages Data Instead of English Data?

Tags: java, android, localization

**i need a help i want to display two different languages data in android first one is arabic second is hindi.
instead of english data all data in arabic or hindi.

can we put the arbic or hindi data in deafult strings.xml file.

or

create two different resource files in arabic and hindi than programmatically changes the language through Localization.

*i need a solution please help me which is best solution or any other solution.*

Answer (score 2):

In android you can easily put language translations in resource qualifier directories.
`res/values/strings.xml` is the default string which will be shown when the string is not translated.

To translate to arabic, you can create a new strings file
`res/values-ar/strings.xml` which will contain the translated strings but with the same resource names.

You can find more information from the google docs
[How to create alternative resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization#creating-alternatives)

Comment: Thank you brother for your replying..

you can to say i cant put the other languages data in default strings.xml file? i create the alternative reaources.

in case in one activity i show the both language arabic or hindi data how we can do that?